# android thread reset

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, reset

my code is:

```
public class EventDialog2 extends Dialog implements OnTouchListener{

    TextView textv;
    Context con;
    Thread t;
    int flag=0;
    public EventDialog2(Context context, int dialogslideanim) {
        super(context, dialogslideanim);
        con = context;

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog2);
        getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        timing();
        LinearLayout line = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear2);
        line.setOnTouchListener(this);
        line.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(con);
            tv.setText("TestProcess " + i);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            line.addView(tv);

        }

    }


    private void timing() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(flag==1){
        t.stop();

            flag=0;
        }

        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {

                    t.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }


                dismiss();

            }
        });
        t.start();
    }


    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("touched");
        flag=1;
        timing();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here thread is working perfectly as it will sleep after 3 seconds. But i need that the thread should get **reset** when we touched in the dialog and should sleep after 3 seconds from the touch. Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand.  You don't seem to be doing anything on the thread except putting it to sleep. What do you want to happen after 3 seconds?

Comment: after 3 seconds, dialog will dismiss. But i need that if we touch on the dialog, it should dismiss only after 3 seconds when touch is released.

Comment: what is the situation now?is there any error?or the touch didn't work? I suggest to use log instead of this  System.out.println("touched");

Comment: no errors. touch is also detected. i only want to reset the sleep time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to test if it has been 3 seconds since that last touch before you call dismiss();  Here's how I would do it.

```
public class EventDialog2 extends Dialog implements OnTouchListener{

    TextView textv;
    Context con;
    Thread t;
    int flag=0;
    Long lastTouchHappenedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Handler handle = new Handler();

    public EventDialog2(Context context, int dialogslideanim) {
        super(context, dialogslideanim);
        con = context;

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog2);
        getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        handle.postDelayed(delayDismis, 3000);

        LinearLayout line = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear2);
        line.setOnTouchListener(this);
        line.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(con);
            tv.setText("TestProcess " + i);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            line.addView(tv);

        }

    }


    private Runnable delayDismis = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTouchHappenedAt >= 3000){
                    dismiss();
                    {
            }
        };


    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("touched");
        flag=1;
        lastTouchHappenedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
        handle.postDelayed(delayDismis, 3000);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: ya it working good,dialog shows and dismiss after 3 seconds.And also the thread refreshes when a touch happens.But I want to keep the dialog open if the user keeps touching the screen,Now it will dismiss even if the user is using the dialog.I tried to implement it in OnTouch>Action_Move. But its a dialog extended class Action_move is not detecting.Is there any way to Detect Action_UP,Action_Move,Action_Down in a dialog extended class.